# How to make AngularJS not to prefix hash-fragment with "/"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, window.location, angular-routing

I am using a third party service on my site with its own authentication flow. There is an opportunity to reset password. This feature has the following flow. You become the email with the link on yoursite.com/#xxx=123456

After you enter this page third party library is downloaded, and after some init process it checks the location url for #xxx=\d+ fragment to make some ajax call and prompt some ui modals

```
var hashKeyElements = window.location.toString().match('#xxx=(.*)');
```

There is no way to change the way they are doing it.
And here is the problem - Angular rewrites yoursite.com/#xxx=123456 to yoursite.com/#/xxx=123456 and after that regexp is not matched

I tried to create double # in url but it causes errors.

**UPDATE:** Using angular 1.2.4, it's not a SPA and all of the related links should not be prevented and pushed via pushState

Thank you

Comment: I checked again and it seems that angular.js (all versions) does not add hashes (`/#/`) to your URL unless you use $routeProvider and `html5Mode=false`. Is there anything you do with `$location` within your app?

Comment: Ye, I used $location to read .search(). Tested it on blank page with angular, $locationProvider is not injected and initiated, no rewrite is applied. Thanks a lot, great job, man!

Comment: I updated my answer, glad to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### update

After you mentioned that you are not using client-side routing I checked again and it seems that angular.js (all versions) does not add hashes (/#/) to URL unless you use `$locationProvider` or `$routeProvider` even when `html5Mode=false`. 
`

---

### If you do client-side routing or using $location:

you need to use html5Mode - [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.%24location):

```
app.config(function($locationProvider){
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true)
})
```

Comment: Sorry, looks like I provided not enough info, the problem is that I am not using client-side routing and it's not a SPA, so i need all the related links to be redirected to other pages. Thanks

Comment: If you do not use routing angular should not rewrite your url at all. What version of angular you are using?

Comment: Sorry, updated the question: 1.2.4 version. I only use ngSanitize, ngCookie and ngAnimate. But I can find parseAppUrl method in angular.js which is called by LocationHtml5Url or LocationHashbangUrl